# Equation of a line passing through a point and forming a triangle with the axes

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

How can I find the equation of a line that;

- is passing through the point (8, 6) and
- is forming a triangle of area 12 with the axes

?

So I tried to start using $A = |{\frac{mn}{2}}|$ and got that $m\cdot n$ is either -24 or 24. What now?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem and can share what you have tried as that helps in providing better answers? Regards

Comment: intercept form? perhaps... ..............................................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equation of lines that passes through $(8,6)$ is $y=ax+6-8a$
and with axes that has common points $(0,6-8a),(8-\frac{6}{a},0)$. Then the surface of right triangle is
$$S=\frac{(8-\frac{6}{a})(6-8a)}{2}=12$$

after simplification we get equation

$$16a^2-30a+9=0$$
with solutions
$$a_1=6,a_2=24$$
there exists two lines with such proppertie
$$l_1:y=6x-42$$
$$l_2:y=24x-186$$

Comment: thank you! how did you do the last step?

Comment: In equation $y=ax+6-8a$ you need to put $a_1=6$ and $a_2=24$

Comment: Nice Adi,my friend.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to convince yourself that such a line is determined uniquely by it's intersection point with the x-axis, which allows you to calculate it's intersection point with the y-axis and the area of the resulting triangle.